# Compare variable number of list elements

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I have a list containing a string in each element. I want to compare the characters of each string starting from the first character to the end. The loop loops over the length of the shortest string in the list.

For example:

```
strs = ["flower", "flow", "flight"]
```

The comparison would look something like this:

```
for sub_i in range(len(min(strs, key=len))):
    if(strs[0][sub_i] == strs[1][sub_i] == strs[2][sub_i]):
        #do something
```

How would I expand this so that I can have an arbitrary number of elements in `strs`? (Instead of just 3 in my example)

Comment: What is "do something"? what should happen when comparing the 5th characters where flow only has 4?

Comment: Why do you want to compare them character by character?

Comment: I'm using the length of the shortest string as the maximum value to iterate over

Comment: I want to compare them that way to find the longest prefix in the strings. In the example ```strs``` it is **fl**.

Answer (score 3):

For some k

```
len(set([s[:k] for s in strs])) == 1
```

Example:

```
strs = ["flower", "flow", "flight"]
k = 2
if len(set([s[:k] for s in strs])) == 1:
   # do something
  print ("same")
```

Output:

```
same
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry but I don't understand this bit : ```[s[:k] for s in strs]```, can you please elaborate?

Comment: `s[:k]` gives you first k characters of the string s. So we are making a list of strings of first k characters of all the strings in strs and checking if all of them match via set.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get that. How are you creating a list from a for loop? And how come you have this ```s[:k]``` before the for loop? Is there any documentation or clarification I can get on this topic?

Comment: Its called list comprehension

Answer (score 2):

For arbitrary lengths, you can [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the strings. This will automatically iterated using the length of the shortest string. Then determine if all the letters are the same. Below converts it to a `set()` and checks the length (which will be `1` if all elements are equal), but of course, there are other ways:

```
strs = ["flower", "flow", "flight"]

for letters in zip(*strs):
    if len(set(letters)) == 1:
        # do something
        print(letters)
```

Prints:

```
('f', 'f', 'f')
('l', 'l', 'l')
```